# Smart Pointer vs Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, automatic-ref-counting, smart-pointers

My knowledge on Objective-C and Automatic Reference Counting is very clear. And recently i am learning C++, Smart Pointer. I found that smart pointer and automatic reference counting are pretty much similar.

Though i couldn't find a side by side comparison(similarities and dissimilarities) on smart pointer and automatic reference counting with code sample/example using C++ and Objective-C. SO can anyone please give me a detailed explanation on this ?

EDIT: Here, by Smart Pointers I am indicating only `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: One is a language feature, the other is a library utility built on top of the language.

Comment: C++ has many smart pointers which doesn't have reference counting at all.

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL: Here, by Smart Pointer I am indication only shared_ptr, weak_ptr and unique_ptr.

Comment: In general, smart pointers should only be used when the scope mechanic cannot be used. Always prefer classic declaration, STL(or custom-) containers, class members etc. because it will force you to think about the correct position of each object and, normally, they should have a specification "scope" (derived from their purpose), and they should probably have an actual scope in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers don't necessarily have to be implemented in terms of reference counting.

The `unique_ptr` does not use any form of reference counting - when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope the pointee is destroyed. Therefore the `unique_ptr` is considered to be as efficient as a raw pointer, which is nice: in cases where exclusive ownership can be used you have both automatic memory management and performance comparable to row pointer based implementation.

The `shared_ptr` is normally implemented using some form of reference counting, because it models shared ownership: when there are no more owners the resource is destroyed.